# Restrict input 0.00 - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, rounding

I have an input textbox

I'am using `Math.ceil` to round off the values entered with decimal in it.

```
Math.ceil(value)
```

If i input `1.2` it will be rounded off to `2`

If i input `3.9` it will be rounded off to `4`

If i input `0.0` or `0.00` it does nothing.

How to restrict user entering `0.00`?

Comment: I don't really get what you are want to happen? Could you provide us with a set of input values and their expected result?

Comment: Math.ceil(value > 0 ? value : 1)
Are you looking for this, or?

Comment: Looks like your regex allows more that single decimal.

Comment: You can't round with regex.

Comment: I have edited the question. Basically i need to restrict the user entering `0.00`

Comment: `if (input === 0) {  input = 1 }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if HTML is what you want but I would also suggest using

```
<input type="number" min="1">
```

of course you would still need to verify the input

```
if (typeof input === 'number') {
    if (input >= 1) {
        if (input.toString().indexOf('.') > -1) {
            input = Math.ceil(input);
        }
    } else {
        input = 1;
    }
} else {
***********
}
```

but it should restrict the user from submitting 0 or 0.00 as long as you still verify it